# Iterating and making decision through a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've been trying to iterate through a NumPy array. I'm trying to check if every element of the array is greater than or equal to 0.1. If an element is greater than or equal to 0.1 the code should append a list.

The array elements should have numbers which where processed in another function. Example:

```
[[-0.68454815]
 [-0.6868374 ]
 [-0.72553124]
 [-0.72324855]
 [-0.69258814]
 [ 0.30578739]
 [ 0.2679637 ]
 [ 0.27038732]
 [-0.62690676]
 [ 0.372456  ]
 [ 0.32854353]
 [ 0.33191556]
 [-0.6357395 ]
 [ 0.3649385 ]
 [ 0.31940787]
 [ 0.32325424]
 [-0.71096214]
 [ 0.29032854]
 [ 0.2589025 ]
 [ 0.26576582]
 [-0.71774566]
 [ 0.28527439]
 [ 0.25350313]
 [ 0.26095643]
 [-0.65131719]
 [ 0.35093124]
 [ 0.30984058]]
```

I'm using this to create a graph with the outputs of the counter_list to create a convergence .

I've checked several threads on here on how to do it and I've came up with something like this:

```
  def looper(self):
        rows = error.shape[0]

        for x in range(0, rows):

                counter_list = list();
                if error(rows) >= 0.2:
                    counter += 1
                    counter_list.append(counter)
                    print("Amount:",counter_list)
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I know that the error `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable` means that you tried to call a numpy array as a function, however I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: We need to know what is what in that code. And where does the code get the error. I'd guess in the line `layer2_error(rows)`?

Comment: this list is one dimensional correct?

Comment: You probably intended this to be an index of the array - `layer2_error(rows)` but that requires square brackets. Possibly `layer2_error[x]` but I don't understand what the code is supposed to do (why do you keep appending `counter`?). If you could give the intended output then this can probably be done in a oneliner and be vectorized rather than using loops.

Comment: Look for a place where you tried to select an element from an ndarray but used round parentheses instead of square brackets.

Comment: So JoseA. I've forgot to change the array name when I've uploaded the question to stackoverflow. It should be fixed now.

To modesitt: Yes, the list should be 1 dimensional.

To roganjosh: I've updated some information in the original post.

Comment: If the array is in 'error' you are calling it as a function in  'error(rows)' it shoudl be  error[rows] - but as below there are better ways to do this

Comment: @MartinBeckett Your suggestion and Matthias suggestion helped me to get rid of the error, however I'm now getting IndexError: index 27 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 27

Comment: error has 27 elements, numbered from 0 to 26. Use "len(errors)-1" in range - or just iterate over errors

Comment: Like this: for x in range(len(error)-1): ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier way to check that condition:

```
import numpy as np

def check(a):
    if np.all(a >= 0.1):
        print("All of them do!")
        return True
    else:
        print("Someone doesnt :'(")
        return False

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.02])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

check(a)
check(b)
```

Output:

```
Someone doesnt :'(
All of them do!
```

**EDIT**

To know the number there is a similar easiness way to do it:

```
print(np.count_nonzero(a < 0.1))  # prints 1
print(np.count_nonzero(a < 0.1))  # prints 0
```

Then you can do something like:

```
e = np.arange(1, np.count_nonzero(a < 0.1) + 1)  # e is [1]
```

This does work with multidimensional arrays. ie:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 0.04, 4, 5, 3],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.02]])
check(a)
print(np.count_nonzero(a < 0.1))
e = np.arange(1, np.count_nonzero(a < 0.1) + 1)
print(e)
```

Output:

```
 Someone doesnt :'(
 2
 [1 2]
```

**EDIT 2**

To do a representation of the increasing errors (error meaning value less than 0.1) the most elegant way I can think of doing it is with a cumulative sum:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([1, 2, 0.03, 4, 5, 0.06, 7, 8]) 
err = np.cumsum(a < 0.1)

plt.plot(np.arange(1, err.shape[0] + 1), err)
plt.savefig('image.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: Increasing number of errors]

Let me know if this is what you wanted!

Comment: I've updated the original post with additional info.

Comment: @ballotra15 Do you need to know the index of the elements greater than or equal to 0.2 (or whatever number)?

Comment: I want to put how many elements are greater than or equal to 0.2 and put them in a list so I can plot them in a graph.

Comment: No I don't want the actual numbers. For example: If the number is 0.2000001 I don't want to know that the element was 0.2000001. I just want a +1 to the list. So in the end the list will look something like this: 1,2,3,4,5...

Comment: @ballotra15 Sorry for the delay, but there you go!

Comment: Thank you for your help it is now working. Since I'm trying to plot 2 lists vs each other, one of my list is 20 characters long and the other is 50 characters long. What do you suggest to do since when you have two lists that aren't the same value will give you an error?  (I'm trying to plot bad facts vs epochs to show convergence)

Comment: @ballotra15 Look at second edit. I think it is ultimately what you want.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm looking to plot the bad facts and the epochs with the information I have in this picture: https://imgur.com/a/pwRhI   . It is a small snippet of a loop where I did your suggestions. When printing, bad facts has the same length as epochs(219), however when I try to plot I still get an error that it isn't the same dimensions.

Comment: Well, I'd need to see the code and know what you are doing. Can you use some site like pastebin, github or whatever you like to show it?

Comment: Well I dont really know why you still use the `counter_list`. The idea is to use the list of values to find out the number of errors in a vectorized way and not loop for each value. Imagine we have a list of values as `a = np.array([1, 2, 0.03, 4])` then when we do `b = np.cumsum(a < 0.2)` the first thing numpy does is find the values that are less than 0.2 and construct a new array (`[False, False, True, False]`) then this array goes to `cumsum`. Cumsum sums each value in a cummulative way, meaning that the value at index `i` of the new array is sum(old[:i] + old[i]). Giving `b=[0, 0, 1, 1]`

Comment: @ballotra15 Using this, no matter how many numbers less than 0.2 you have in `a`. The length of `b` will always remain the same as the length of `a`.

Comment: I've tried using b = np.cumsum(a <0.2) , however I've still got the same problem. In fact you can see it in the pastebin.

Comment: What about the counter which is in the train function to count the amount of epochs?

Answer (score 2):

If this list is one dimensional, you can try just using numpys slicing.

```
return data[data >= 0.1]
```

returning a `np.array` where every `item >= 0.1` in the `data np array` is kept.